# jQuery .each only works for first item

Tags: jquery, each, preload

I am trying to preload an html file whose contents will subsequently be used on several expandable buttons spread throughout a website.

The problem is that only the content of the first button of the page gets loaded this way, the rest of the buttons show nothing when expanded.

I do have noticed that there are other questions here on SO about similar issues, but none of the solutions I've come across seemed to work in this case. Therefore, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Relevant part of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     
    var thisLink = $("a.ajax-link");
    var targetUrl = thisLink.attr("data-href");
    var target = thisLink.data("ajaxtarget");
 
    $(target).each(function( index, btn ) {
        $(this).load(targetUrl, function () {
          console.log('Success');
        });
      });
    
});
```

If there is any other piece of information that could be of use to you, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Note, your ajax code make no sense, you fetch the file but you don't use html anywhere. If this is just example then you can remove the $.ajax because it's not related to the question since it don't do anything.

Comment: You are right, @jcubic. I just copy/pasted the exact part of the code from the script thinking that it might help someone spot the error. Cleaning things up now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the selector `a.ajax-link` selects all your expandable links, then `var thisLink = $("a.ajax-link");` holds an array of all your expandable link elements on your page. Therefore with `var target = thisLink.data("ajaxtarget");` you only receive the data attribute of the first element in the array.

The solution is simple:

You need to run your `foreach` loop for every expandable link and get the corrosponding data from each of these links.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://example.com/path/to/html/file",
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(html) {
        $.each($("a.ajax-link"), function() {
          let targetUrl = $(this).data('href');
          let $target = $($(this).data('ajaxtarget'));
          $target.load(targetUrl, function() {
            console.log('success');
          });
        });
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. For the detailed explanation too; it really helped me understand better how .each works.